# IE10 function load setinterval not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, setinterval

I have this piece of code:

```
$(function(){
    function load()
    {
        $("#queuerefresh").load("1.txt");
    }

    load();
    setInterval(load,1000);
});
```

Using: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Which loads the content of a text file onto a div. This is set to refresh every 1 second so that as the text file is updated it shows in the div. This is working perfectly in Chrome however, it is not refreshing in IE10 unless I manually refresh the whole page? Please help.

Comment: Do you need to have a function inside a function?

Comment: @MatthewRiches That is the jQuery document ready shorthand. It means that the dom will have loaded before triggering the load function

Comment: @Sam I know, but does he really need to wait for document ready if he is loading an external source, if the script is at the bottom of the page the element will be there but I guess maybe it could be in the head seems redundant though - either way an AJAX call could just create the element when it's complete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to me to be a caching problem. You can avoid this by using ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function load()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "1.txt",
            cache: false, // very important in your case
            success: function(data)
            {
                $("#queuerefresh").empty();
                $("#queuerefresh").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    load();
    setInterval(load,1000);
});
```

works for me in Chrome, Firefox as well as in IE

Answer (score 0):

hi just try something like below should work..added some code for ie 10..now check it

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses */
    cache: false
});

    var refreshId = setInterval( function() 
    {
        $("#queuerefresh").load("1.txt");
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: I don't see any significant difference to OP's code that could fix the IE problem. Did you test it?

Comment: he's setting caching to false on ajax, that's pretty much it.